# How can I hide a DOM element that contains no text?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I am wondering how to hide a DOM element in JavaScript if it doesn't contain any text, for example:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li></li> <!-- Element to hide -->
</ul>
```

I've currently written:

```js
var point = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < point.length; i++){
   if(point[i].text==""){
      point[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `points[i].text`, use `points[i].innerHTML`.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("li:empty")` keeps you from having to loop and compare

Comment: or better yet, don't even use JS, use CSS:  `li:empty{display:none;}`

Comment: Thank you for all your answers but I'm only using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` property and remove the empty spaces first before making a check againts it.

```
 if(!/[\S]/.test(point[i].innerHTML)) { 
    point[i].style.display = "none";
 }
```

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard, you want `textContent`

Comment: @elclanrs My bad.. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! I used the previous solution and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jQuery for this, it will smooth out the browser differences:

```
$('li').each(function (){
    if($(this).html()==="") {
        $(this).css({"display":"none"});   
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm only using Javascript. But I will count with it when I learn jQuery.

Comment: Ok well I would highly recommend using jQuery it makes life easier and the syntax is not as scary as it looks like :)